# UIScrollView with UIPinchGesture

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have a UIScrollView with a UIPinchGesture attached to it. My problem is though if I do a pinch gesture it moves the UIScrollView's and can see this when NSLogging the UIScrollView's X/Y. I was wondering if anyone has any ideas to prevent this happening on the scrollview?

I already set the minimum and maximum zoom scale:

```
[scrollView setMaximumZoomScale: 1.0];
[scrollView setMinimumZoomScale: 1.0];
```

Also I have subclasses the UIScrollView and implemented the touchesBegan and touchesEnded but I am unsure how I would ignore a touch on the scrollview if 2 fingers are used?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

you can wisely use ScrollEnabled property.

Also to cancel touch when two fingers are used,

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

    if ([allTouches count] > 1)
    {
        [self touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else
    {
        //pass touch.
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an NSLog(@"2 Touches") in first part of if but you do not get a log message until you move your fingers from the screen. Therefore when pinching it still moves the scrollview.